# Display UISearchBar over tableView when user touches UIBarButtonItem

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview, uisearchbar, uisearchdisplaycontroller

In my iOS app, I would like to have a right side search button in my `UINavigationController`, and when a user touches the button, the `UISearchBar` above my `UITableView` is shown.

I would like the `UISearchBar` hidden when the view loads, and then hidden again when the user clicks the **Cancel** button in the `UISearchDisplayController`.

I've searched everywhere and cannot find an example. Help?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a nice sample project [here](https://github.com/versluis/Table-Seach-2013). The key points are:

1.Hide the Search Bar before presenting the View:

```
-(void)viewWillAppear:(BOOL)animated {
    [self hideSearchBar];        
}

-(void)hideSearchBar {
   CGRect newBounds = self.tableView.bounds;
   newBounds.origin.y = newBounds.origin.y + self.searchBar.bounds.size.height;
   self.tableView.bounds = newBounds;
}
```

2.On the action target for your search button, display the Search Bar

```
 // make the search bar visible
 // code example from https://github.com/versluis/Table-Seach-2013 to deal with iOS 7 behavior

-(IBAction)displaySearchBar:(id)sender {

    [self.tableView scrollRectToVisible:CGRectMake(0, 0, 1, 1) animated:YES];

    NSTimeInterval delay;
    if (self.tableView.contentOffset.y >1000) delay = 0.4;
    else delay = 0.1;
    [self performSelector:@selector(activateSearch) withObject:nil afterDelay:delay];

}

- (void)activateSearch
{
    [self.tableView scrollRectToVisible:CGRectMake(0, 0, 1, 1) animated:NO];
    [self.searchBar becomeFirstResponder];

}
```

3.Finally, hide the SearchBar when Cancel is clicked

```
-(void)searchBarCancelButtonClicked:(UISearchBar *)searchBar {
    [self hideSearchBar];
}
```

Comment: This solution does not work very "smoothly" in that when the user hits Cancel they are left in the middle of the table and the search bar is visible after hiding cancel again.

Comment: I moved hideSearchBar to viewWillAppear, which helped with the positioning of the TableView. In my build it returns to the top position. I also can't reproduce the problem with the SearchBar staying visible after hiding cancel again. Testing on iOS 7.

Comment: What is the purpose of the timer in `displaySearchBar`?

Comment: I removed the timer from `displaySearchBar` and then added a timer to the `searchBarCancelButtonClicked` method to prevent a "jump" on the screen